# Drupal: How to define variables in one module functions and call it from another in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I writing a module for Drupal 7. It must get current `$node` variable in one function, e.g. `hook_init()` or similar, and this variable should be accessible from another function. I found discussion about `node_load(arg(1))` and the author of solution said that performance is no concern because of caching.

So, should I call `node_load()` in every function I need not being afraid of performance issues of are there any other ways to pass variables between module functions?

To be more exact: I've placed a block with module on pages with a certain node types and in hook_block_view function I need to access to current node object. I'm succeeded using node_load so far. But maybe there is a better way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to call `node_load` in every function, especially if the node is loaded from the database. Maybe if you post some code with an explanation of what you're trying to achieve, you may get more help from others.

Comment: I'll try to be more exact. I've placed a block with module on pages with a certain node types and in hook_block_view function I need to access to current node object. I'm succeeded using node_load so far. But maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In drupal 7 `node_load()` calls `entity_load()`, which caches the results, so if you call `node_load()` twice, it will be returned from cache.

Using `node_load()` is better solution than passing global variables between modules, especially if you use some third-party caching modules (APC, memcached or other). If you care about performance just try to use one of these modules (I prefer memcached).